# Появилась реклама на мобильной версии сайта

Tags: api, карты, реклама

После добавление API карты яндекс на сайт тильда, появилась реклама, причём только на мобильных версиях сайта.
Сайт пока тестовый. http://project2834973.tilda.ws/ Все коды были взяты с сайта яндекс.
Отрывок кода:

```
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&amp;apikey=<мойключAPI>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="placemark.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Возможно дело в том, что протокол не HTTPS и в провайдере (реклама только у людей с определенным провайдером, как выяснилось)**

Это только часть рекламы. Бывает поп ап выскакивает даже.
[image: скриншот1]

Comment: Возможно это ваш провайдер добавляет рекламу, в примере и на скриншоте вы используете http что позволяет вмешиваться в трафик

Comment: Попробуйте сделать редирект с http на https, вижу что сайт уже поддерживает и сертификаты

Comment: @devnull Да, всё дело было в https, спасибо)